# NodeJS - HBS - Javascript calling Sqlite DB to Insert Data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am building a website that uses npm and sqlite to localhost hosting.

I am using Handlebars, nodejs, html and js on the site.

My question is. I have two buttons as shown below:

[image: button image]

The functionality I want is:

- When the user clicks the button IN - it sends to the database Boolean  `"TRUE"` and if it is `TRUE` the user is marked as present.
- Button OUT is similar, however Boolean `"FALSE"` and marked as `"FAULT"`.

So I need this function to call my `db.development.sqlite` and call the `Clock_in` table then update the `State` column to `true` or `false` depending on which button was clicked.

I don't know how I should call the DB and the table to change its values.

My website is using the DB and works fine, *Updates*, *Inserts* and *Deletes* other data.

The only one I can't change is that one.

I am working with with this code:

```html
<p class="">Clock-in</p>
<input class="form-control date datePickerClockIn" name="somedate" type="date" max="2013-12-25">

<button id="inDay" type="button" class="inToday" onclick="inDay()" value="PRESENTE">IN</button> 
<button id="outDay"class="outToday" onclick="outDay()" value="FALTOU">OUT</button>

<script>
    function inDay() {
        var sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();

        // Default mode is sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite.OPEN_CREATE
        var db = new sqlite.Database('timeoff-management\db.development.sqlite');
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO clock_in VALUES ("Hello")');
        });


    }

    function outDay() {

    }

</script>
```

This is the page where the code is - Page Code(Sorry about the configuration but is in HBS) :

Comment: So you are trying to access the db from the client?

Comment: @MartinReiche yes, I want to acess the db and update the table data when I click the button and then hide them. Its an attendance checker.

Comment: Why you don't send data to server, and access to db from Node.js ??

Comment: If you´re using node, you should expose an endpoint to do that. Why are you using sqllite at the client? Are you using emscripten port of sqllite?

Comment: What you want to do is insecure and an anti-pattern. This kind of code completely expose you DB